# How to assign IP address to an Ingress Controller ON K8S cloud providers - EKS and GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

How do I assign an IP address into an Ingress controller?
I am using AWS EKS and also GCP GKE.

If possible is to get a private IP address from the cloud provider. I don't want it to be available to the public. 
I use it as internal load-balancer using HaProxy.

I saw this article but it not have enough details. 
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/static-ip

Thanks 
Yaniv

Comment: in the link provided by you, you already have an example https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/static-ip/static-ip-svc.yaml

Comment: Well the example is for GKE and using Nginx as ingress controller.  What about EKS?

Comment: you can use that for gke and eks too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the nginx ingress controller and use internal load balancers for as the service. Using an internal LB will use an internal IP and you can define that internal IP (if you want) in the service definition.

This will not work with the cloud provider ingress controller. If you use the GCE or AWS ingress, you will either get a GCE HTTP(S) LB or an elastic IP. Using the Nginx ingress controller will provide you a workaround